# Evaluation of $\int_\limits{-1}^{3}\frac{x\ln |x|}{1+x^4}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

> Evaluation of $$\int_\limits{-1}^{3}\frac{\arctan(1+x^2)}{x}dx$$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$I = \int_\limits{-1}^3\arctan(1+x^2)\cdot \frac{1}{x}dx$$

Using By parts, We get

$$I = \left[\arctan (1+x^2)\cdot \ln|x|\right]^{3}_{-1}-2\int_\limits{-1}^3\frac{x\ln |x|}{1+x^4}dx$$

Now How can i solve it , Help required, Thanks

Comment: Maybe, you are looking for the $Principal\ Value$. Otherwise, it diverges ' logarithmically around' $x = 0$ as $\texttt{@Jacky Chong}$ already pointed out in his answer.

Comment: that's how the principalvalue integral looks:
$$
\frac{1}{4} \left(\pi  \log (3)+i \left(\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{9}{2}+\frac{9 i}{2}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{9}{2}-\frac{9 i}{2}\right)\right)\right)
$$

Answer (score 3):

By continuity, there exists  a neighborhood about zero such that
\begin{align}
|\arctan 1 -\arctan (1+x^2)| < \frac{1}{4} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \arctan1<\frac{1}{4}+\arctan (1+x^2)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
0<\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{4}}{x} < \frac{\arctan(1+x^2)}{x}
\end{align}
whenever $r<x<0$ for some $r$.
Now, observe
\begin{align}
\infty =\int^0_{-1} \frac{\frac{\pi-1}{4}}{x}\ dx< \int^0_{-1} \frac{\arctan(1+x^2)}{x}\ dx.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$\arctan(x^2+1) > \arctan (1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

For $x \in (0,\infty)$ as $x^2 > 0 \implies x^2+1 > 1$ and $f(u)=\arctan(u)$ is strictly increasing on $x \in (0,\infty)$.

Hence,

$$\int_{0}^{3} \frac{\arctan (x^2+1)}{x} > \int_{0}^{3} \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{x} \to \infty$$

Answer (score 1):

The integral does not converge as has been explained above, however it does have a finite principal value (apparently PV is $\frac{31423231}{21789317}$ or 1.44214  )

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> The original integral clearly diverges logarithmically "at $\ds{x = 0}$". We'll evaluate the *Principal Value* by assuming it was the OP original intention.

\begin{align}
&\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-1}^{3}{\arctan\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\bracks{%
\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}{\arctan\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over x}\,\dd x +
\int_{\epsilon}^{3}{\arctan\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\ \
\overbrace{\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-1}^{1}{\arctan\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over x}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{=\ 0}}\ +\
\int_{1}^{3}{\arctan\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over x}\,\dd x\quad
\pars{\begin{array}{c}
\mbox{Integrate by parts}\\ \mbox{the last integral}
\end{array}}
\\[5mm]  = &\
\ln\pars{3}\arctan\pars{10} -
\int_{1}^{3}\ln\pars{x}\,{2x \over \pars{1 + x^{2}}^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \,\,\,\stackrel{x^{2}\ \mapsto\ x}{=} &\,\,\,
\ln\pars{3}\arctan\pars{10} -
{1 \over 2}\int_{1}^{9}{\ln\pars{x} \over \pars{1 + x}^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\ln\pars{3}\arctan\pars{10} -
{1 \over 2}\int_{1}^{9}\ln\pars{x}
\pars{{1 \over x + 1 - \ic} - {1 \over x + 1 + \ic}}{1 \over 2\ic}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\ln\pars{3}\arctan\pars{10} +
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\int_{1}^{9}{\ln\pars{x} \over -1 + \ic - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\ln\pars{3}\arctan\pars{10} +
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\int_{1}^{9}{%
\ln\pars{\bracks{-1 + \ic}\braces{x/\bracks{-1 + \ic}}} \over
1 - x/\pars{-1 + \ic}}\,{\dd x \over -1 + \ic}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{x/\pars{-1 + \ic}\ \mapsto\ x}{=} &\,\,\,
\ln\pars{3}\arctan\pars{10} +
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\int_{-\pars{1 + \ic}/2}^{-9\pars{1 + \ic}/2}{%
\ln\pars{\bracks{-1 + \ic}x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[1cm] = &\
\ln\pars{3}\arctan\pars{10} +
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\left\lbrace%
-\ln\pars{1 + {9 \over 2}\,\bracks{1 + \ic}}\ln\pars{9}\right.
\\[5mm]  &\phantom{\ln\pars{3}\arctan\pars{10} +
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\braces{}} +
\left.\int_{-\pars{1 + \ic}/2}^{-9\pars{1 + \ic}/2}{%
\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x\right\rbrace
\\[1cm] = &\
\ln\pars{3}\arctan\pars{10} - \ln\pars{3}
\arctan\pars{9 \over 11} -
{1 \over 2}\,\Im
\int_{-\pars{1 + \ic}/2}^{-9\pars{1 + \ic}/2}
\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[#ffe,15px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{{1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{3}\,\pi -
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\braces{%
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{-\,{9 \over 2}\,\bracks{1 + \ic}} -
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{-\,{1 + \ic \over 2}}}}}\ \approx 1.4421
\end{align}

> Note that
>   
>   $\ds{\arctan\pars{10} - \arctan\pars{9/11} =
> \arctan\pars{\bracks{10 - 9/11}/\braces{1 + 10\bracks{9/11}}} =
> \arctan\pars{1} = \pi/4}$.